# Liferay pages export stuck in queued state

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.2 version. I tried to export pages with permission and the export process is stuck in queued state for a while now. 
Liferay is running and it does not pick the background-task queued.

[image]

Please advise how this can be solved.

Tried to restart liferay tomcat with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running below SQL in lportal database did the trick.

```
DELETE FROM BackgroundTask;
DELETE FROM Lock_;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you stop Liferay server during background task execution?

If you killed server perhaps background tasks become inconsistent,

Execute following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM BackgroundTask
SELECT * FROM Lock_
```

And check background tasks status and locks.

Comment: thank you @jorgediaz-lr, Lock_ had a stale entry and deleting it did the trick.